# C-preprocessor: extract [0...N] args from __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c-preprocessor

How can I extract [0...N] arguments from **VA_ARGS** assuming that N will be less or equal to the number of arguments.

Example:

```
#define MY_SEQ r0, r1, r2,  r3,  r4,  r5,  r6,  r7, \
               r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15

#define EXTRACT_N(n, SEQ) {... magic ...}

...

EXTRACT_N(5, (MY_SEQ()));

should expand to:

{r0, r1, r2, r3, r4};
```

It's ok to assume that sequence elements are of this form WHATEVER##N where N is Nth element.

I'm looking for some nice solution to this problem NOT using BOOST, e.g. I'd like to understand how it can be done.

I did it using iterative approach, but I'd like to know if there is some other way to do it.
Here's how I implemented it:

```
#define EXTRACT_1(t0)               t0
#define EXTRACT_2(t0, t1)           EXTRACT_1(t0),t1
#define EXTRACT_3(t0, t1, t2)       EXTRACT_2(t0, t1),t2
#define EXTRACT_4(t0, t1, t2, t3)   EXTRACT_3(t0, t1, t2),t3
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in the general case. The c preprocessor is not that flexible.

You might have something like

```
#define EXTRACT_N(N,A) EXTRACTTHEM ## N(A)
```

and have

```
#define EXTRACTTHEM1(X, ...) X
#define EXTRACTTHEM2(X,Y, ...) X,Y
```

etc

(it is easy to generate an arbitrary large, but bounded, set of such macros).

There are more powerful processors than `cpp`, e.g. `m4` or [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)

You might consider instead generating your C or C++ code (using your own script, or some generator) and having your building system (e.g. `Makefile`) take care of generating the C code from something different.

Comment: Well, you contradict yourself by saying it's impossible and they showing a working example. That's the way I did it in my code but I was curious if there is a better solution (perhaps with boost preprocessor). I absolutely don't care about anything else other than c-preprocessor, since this code is part of real c/c++ project.

Comment: I edited the question showing the iterative approach that I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: I feel that you have a good case for generating the C++ code elsewhere (perhaps with `gpp` which seems `cpp` friendly)

Comment: No, I cannot, I use that macro as part of some C++ code and there is no way (it won't be accepted by the project in other words). I'll accept your answer, but I feel here should be some quirky magical solution to do it (just like to count number of arguments).

Comment: Just generate `#define EXTRACTTHEM1` ... `#define EXTRACTTHEM100` .. in an `#include`-d header. That would be practically enough...

Comment: I got what you mean, I don't need that many (up to 16 is OK), but I had to generate a few similar loops and was thinking there is a better way. If I had to generate something I would simply write a c++ hello world app that does that for me ;)